# How do I clear a C++ array?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How do I clear/empty a C++ array? Theres [`array::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/array/fill/), but looks like its C++11 only? I am using VC++ 2010. How do I empty it (reset to all 0)?

Comment: Resetting all to 0 is not emptying.

Comment: What do you mean clear/empty? An array is never empty.

Comment: Huh? The array of zero-size is mostly empty.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker that only applies to dynamically allocated arrays, and is *the only case* where an array can be empty. Hence, one cannot empty an array.

Comment: I only didn't like the "never empty" part :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Right, I should have phrased it "an array can never be *emptied*"

Comment: @juanchopanza More generally: the size of an array can never be changes.  (Emptying is just a special case of the more general rule.)  And of course, since there's no case where you'd ever dynamically allocate an array, it's probably OK to say that an array can never be empty.

Comment: Ok, what I meant is setting all values to zero then. Whats your interpretation of emptying an array then?

Comment: @JiewMeng, zero element is also an element. Empty is an array that contains nothing, not even zero elements.

Comment: In particular, with collection classes I'd call an array of zero size empty.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
std::fill_n(array, elementCount, 0);
```

Assuming `array` is a normal array (e.g. `int[]`)

Comment: The C++ standard type (since C++11) array<T, N> has a member function fill(Value) will do.  The underlying implementation may use memset.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming a C-style array `a` of size `N`, with elements of a type implicitly convertible from `0`, the following sets all the elements to values constructed from `0`.

```
std::fill(a, a+N, 0);
```

Note that this is not the same as "emptying" or "clearing".

**Edit**: Following james Kanze's suggestion, in C++11 you could use the more idiomatic alternative

```
std::fill( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), 0 );
```

In the absence of C++11, you could roll out your own solution along these lines:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N> T* end_(T(&arr)[N]) { return arr + N; }

template <typename T, std::size_t N> T* begin_(T(&arr)[N]) { return arr; }

std::fill( begin_( a ), end_( a ), 0 );
```

Comment: In C++11, you could also write `std::fill( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), 0 )`.  Somehow this seems more idiomatic.  (And is there anyone using pre-C++11 who doesn't have something similar in their toolkit?)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, what I interpret it as is setting it to its default values, so for int, its 0? Ok, maybe its not the right word to use. But I'd like to know what it actually meant

Comment: @JamesKanze Agreed, but since OP implied C++11 was out of bounds, I presented the less elegant solution. I will added some (not fully tested) home-made solution.

Comment: @JiewMeng you could make that clearer in your question. Note you didn't even mention your array was holding `ints`!

Answer (score 8):

```
std::fill(a.begin(),a.end(),0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you want to populate the array with something other than *intrinsic* values, *std::fill* wont cut it; instead I found *std::generate* useful. e.g. I had a vector of lists I wanted to initialize

```
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [] () { return std::list<X>(); });
```

You can do ints too e.g.

```
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [n = 0] () mutable { return n++; });
```

or just

```
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [] (){ return 0; });
```

but I imagine std::fill is faster for the simplest case

Answer (score 0):

`for (auto& a : SomeArray) a = 0;`

Answer (score -1):

If only to 0 then you can use `memset`:

```
int* a = new int[6];

memset(a, 0, 6*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Please, no `memset`. Use the appropriate C++ equivalents instead of the C functions. And don’t use manually managed memory for dynamic arrays. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Why not? `memset` is just fine, but only provided this is a kind of array the OP meant. Another - more serious - issue is that the second parameter is count. Meaning `6*sizeof(*a)`.

Comment: @Michael Among other things, it only works for PODs so it has very limited scope. It simply has no place in C++, it’s wholly replaced by `std::fill`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, of course. But Denis did show what type it applies too.

Comment: No, `memset` is still allowed even if you dislike it. And it's a joy to see memset once in a while for an old-fashioned hacker ;-)

That said, I'm glad we both expressed our opinions. This way the empact will neither be eradication memset nor abuse thereof ;)

Comment: I agree that memset is only for PODs and not fully acceptable in C++ but i wrote only if you need zero's inside

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker `memset` only works for integral types.  It's not even guaranteed for floating point (although I've never heard of a case where it didn't work for them), and there have certainly been implementations where it didn't work for pointer.  And of course, it doesn't work at all for most class types.

Comment: @JamesKanze, of course not. Whatever one is using one should be aware of limitations.

Comment: @Michael My point is that using it has *no* advantages, and sometimes has disadvantages, and that alone is reason enough to ban it from code. For the same reason we advocate always using prefix-increment, even in cases where it makes no difference, in place of postfix-increment (obviously only when both are semantically correct). Having a single “always use this” rule is a no-brainer. Not having such a rule requires you to remember caveats and specifics.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, exactly the reason I prefer not to have such rules ;)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Hmm, I don’t understand that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, nevermind then. I prefer thinking and knowing over having no-brainer rules.

Comment: @Michael There’s a difference between knowing and *being forced to think about it* on every usage. I know about the intricacies of cache invalidation (to some extent), I prefer not having to think about it for every variable access.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree with you: `memset` is too error prone, given that there are safer alternatives (which are typically faster as well).  It has the additional disadvantage in what it tells the reader: that the author doesn't really know C++.

Comment: Also the code above is broken. `a+6*sizeof(int)`. Will generate a point way past the end of the array.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, who's forcing whom? I think you misinterpret me. Nobody's forcing anyone into using `memset` (you might have noticed, I've given `std::fill` as an answer myself) — you were trying to force *not* to. And this is what I do not like. It is akin to forcing people to not use archaic expressions in human language. People use exact wording that they want to at this particular moment and this usage — unless taken too far — does not signify not knowing the language or anything negative for that matter. There's always more than one road to Rome.

Comment: @Michael I am not forcing anything on anyone. I recommend best practices (*especially* in a learning environment, i.e. here on Stack Overflow) based on objective arguments. That’s all. And in this context I would also like to note that the downvote is *not* mine – I downvote wrong or misleading answers, not those I disagree with stylistically.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, well, then we're misinterpreting each other ;) And, I have to admit, that your initial comment *not* coupled with a downvote looks somewhat better to me. It's hard to tell now, but I think I did assume the downvote was yours back then.

Answer (score -1):

Hey i think The fastest way to handle that kind of operation is to memset() the memory.

Example-

**`memset(&myPage.pageArray[0][0], 0, sizeof(myPage.pageArray));`**

**A similar C++ way would be to use std::fill**

```
char *begin = myPage.pageArray[0][0];
char *end = begin + sizeof(myPage.pageArray);
std::fill(begin, end, 0);
```

Comment: `std::memset` is not faster than `std::fill`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph cole `std::fill(buf, buf + n, '\0');` would be transformed to `memset`

Comment: @AndrewPilikin Exactly. That’s my point.